# Change location of misplaced/stray part of a Visual Basic solution

Tags: vb.net

**Embed a part of a solution that accidently got linked from outside**

I am not fully aware how all parts of a VB.net solution are interlinked.
When I wanted to work at home, I put files on a USB stick to continue there.
That didn't work at all.
Now my work is like a fallen cup: I got all parts but they don't work together anymore.

I can only build the project when the USB stick is connected.
Every attempt to get the file back onto the desktop PC has failed.

What can I do to get the file onto the desktop computer so the USB stick is no longer needed?

What I tried: copy manually (not working) and ADD EXISTING ITEM (not seen by Visual Studio)

[image]

Comment: If you include a [ `.vb`, `.designer.vb`, `.resx` ] combo with _the same name_ in your project (in the same folder of course), they should amalgamate into the lost form you're looking for. In your screenshot, it seems like you're trying to frankenstein files with different names.

Comment: I chose every part of v01 and used “save as” to give each part the right “v03” name. That worked until I tried “thumbnail meister v01.vb”. Then it didn’t work. There already is a file called like that on the hdd. But it never loads. The one one the usb is needed all the time for each build. Can you tell me in steps what to do?

Comment: I did the “save as” action to no longer have to need the usb files btw. That actually worked. I saved them on the hdd that way. Except for this one file.

Comment: You can copy and paste them in the file explorer (window's one) with no problems, then you'll have to set up identical names manually, refresh your solution explorer, show all files, include the "new" files in the current project. That really should do it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to think along. I had so little knowledge of the hierarchy system/solution/application that I completely garbled my work. A colleague raked out the dirt and made it whole again. I now understand a project is best kept as one folder. 
For new versions I just copy/paste the folder and increment the name from v01 to v02.

Comment: Thanks for giving closure, I was wondering what happened to you. In case you'd like to know, I did the same back when I was in school (keeping stuff on a flashdrive), but now I use GitHub with TortoiseGit to keep track of my versioning. It's waaaay better, and also free. I wish I knew that back then.